# How to properly reference classes output by Source Generators in C#

Tags: c#, csharp-source-generator

A .NET 5 console app uses an Analyzer that includes a Source Generator to generate test cases as classes. These are output to a temporary folder like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
  <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\GeneratedFiles</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
  <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>False</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
  <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>True</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
```

The generated classes are referenced in the main Program, instantiated, and executed:

```
  await TestFunction("Simple addition - uint.", new SimpleAdditionUint.SimpleAdditionUint(), ba => CheckUint(ba,3));
```

where the above SimpleAdditionUint.SimpleAdditionUint is generated by the Source Generator.

What I am experiencing is that if the folder with the generated files is not included in the csproj, then despite the project successfully building, there are edit-time error diagnostics warning that the classes do not exist.

If I include the output files in the csproj, then at build time I get errors that the types already exist. I would need a pre-build step to empty the included folder.

I am surprised by this behaviour and cannot find anything similar online. Is there some project setting I am missing here?

Comment: "*there are edit-time error diagnostics warning that the classes do not exist*" -- this is an error in Visual Studio somewhere. Source Generators run on any change, and the results are automatically included in the compilation. You should be able to see the generated files under the "Dependencies - Analyzers" node in the Solution Explorer. Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of VS

Comment: @canton7 the files are visible in the folder structure, but not under any Analyzer. It says "This generator is not generating files."

Comment: That does seem to have been happening more recently. It's a Visual Studio issue I think -- it fixes itself (for a while at least) if you restart VS.

Comment: @canton7 error returns almost immediately. ok I will look for workaround. cheers!

Comment: I wonder if things are better in a slightly older version of VS. I don't think I've seen any reports about this on github (although I've hit it myself, and had a user of one of my SGs report it as well). Feel free to open an issue by hitting the speech bubble icon in the top right of VS

Comment: @canton7 ok thanks, i will play around and open an issue.